# Deleting elements from a list via a list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of indices,

```
ind = [0,1,2,5,6,7]
```

And another list of my data:

```
data = [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64]
```

I'd like to only keep the indices of `data` that correspond to the values in `list`:

```
result = [0,1,4,25,36,49]
```

Or reworded, delete the indices in `data` that aren't in the values of `list`.

I think there's some kind of list comprehension I could do but I can't figure it out! Thanks,

Comment: `list(operator.itemgetter(*ind)(data))`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to delete anything, just use a list comprehension to index out of `data` using the indices from `ind`

```
>>> result = [data[i] for i in ind]
>>> result
[0, 1, 4, 25, 36, 49]
```